# href working instead of javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am having an issue with the `a href="#"` still working when the link is clicked - I can see the `console.log()` before the page changes - why is it doing this?

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="brands_by_category_change_name_btn" class="btn btn-primary" >Save</a>
```

**JS:**

```
        $('body').on("click", "#brands_by_category_change_name_btn", function () {

            var self = $(this);
            var id = $("#product_name_head").data("productid");
            var cat_id = $(".product_category_selector").data("id");

            var url = $("#manufacturers_table").data("infourl");

            var state = "0";
            if(self.is(":checked"))
            {
                state = "1";
            }
            var data_array = { 
                    id : id, 
                    cat_id : cat_id, 
                    state : state
                };

                console.log(url);

            //ajaxCall(url, data_array, null, "reload_selected_product_categories");

        });
```

Comment: Check out this similar question and the answers for best practices. 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should pass event parameter to function. And do. Event.preventDefault()   it will stop link from native behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `return false;` at the end of the function will fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Add a `return false;` at the end of your event-handling code. I would do it that way:

```
$("#brands_by_category_change_name_btn").click( 

  // your code...

  return false;

});
```